# Scheduled task results

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

We're trying to retrieve the mapped drives of the logged on user on a Windows 7 client. The code below does this for us when run with an administrator account.

The only thing is, once in a while (when running the code for the first time on a new client) it's not returning the results of the 'PS_Data.txt' file on the first run. When run for a second time the data is returned correctly. For one reason or another the file is populated with the correct data but it's not retrieved.

I've been thinking that the task is too fast deleted so I tried playing with some `Start-Sleep` CmdLets here and there, but nothing really solved it.

```
#$Computer = 'ClientName'; $User = 'LoggedOnUserSamAccountName'

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$TaskName
    )

    $VerbosePreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$Using:VerbosePreference
    $DebugPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$Using:DebugPreference

    $CurrentDir = 'C:\Users\' + $User + '\AppData\Local\Temp'
    $Script     = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Script.ps1'
    $Launcher   = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Launcher.vbs'
    $File       = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Data.txt'

    $File, $Script, $Launcher | Remove-Item -EA Ignore

    # VB is only needed to kick-of the script and suppress the PowerShell window
    # and to set the workdir
    $VBCode = @"
        'run window totally hidden
        Dim oSHELL
        Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        oSHELL.CurrentDirectory = "$CurrentDir"
        oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File .\PS_Script.ps1", 0
        Set oSHELL = Nothing
"@

    $PSCode = {
        Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | Select-Object Name, ProviderName |
            Export-Csv .\PS_Data.txt -NoTypeInformation
    }

    Try {
        $VBCode | Set-Content $Launcher -EA Stop
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created '$Launcher'")

        $PSCode | Set-Content $Script -EA Stop
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created '$Script'")
    }
    Catch {
        throw "User profile folder '$CurrentDir' not found on '$env:COMPUTERNAME'"
    }

    Try {
        #schtasks /create /F /RL HIGHEST /SC ONCE /ST 23:00 /TN $TaskName /TR "wscript.exe $Launcher" /RU "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$User"
        $Task = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
        $Task.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)
        $Task_Folder = $Task.GetFolder('\')
        $Task_TaskDefinition = $Task.NewTask(0)

        $Task_RegistrationInfo = $Task_TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
        $Task_RegistrationInfo.Description = 'This task is created with PowerShell to run with user credentials'
        $Task_RegistrationInfo.Author = 'Powershell'

        $Task_Settings = $Task_TaskDefinition.Settings
        $Task_Settings.Enabled = $True
        $Task_Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $True
        $Task_Settings.Hidden = $False
        $Task_Settings.AllowDemandStart = $True
        $Task_Settings.WakeToRun = $True
        $Task_Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = $False

        $Task_Action = $Task_TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
        $Task_Action.Path = 'wscript.exe'
        $Task_Action.Arguments = $Launcher
        $Task_Action.WorkingDirectory = $CurrentDir

        $Task_Folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName, $Task_TaskDefinition, 6, ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN + '\' + $User), $null, 3) | Out-Null
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is created")

        schtasks /run /TN $TaskName | Write-Verbose
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is started as user '$User'")
        #Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

        # Wait for scheduled task to finish
        while ((& schtasks.exe /query /TN $TaskName /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status -First 1) -eq 'Running') {
            Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled Task '$TaskName' is running")
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        }
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is finished")
    }
    Catch {
        throw "Failed creating/running the scheduled rask '$TaskName' on '$env:COMPUTERNAME': $_"
    }

    # Wait for the data file to be available
    for ($i = 0; $i -le 5; $i++) {
        if (Test-Path $File) {
            Import-Csv $File | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID
            Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created and data imported '$File'")
            $Data = $True
            Break
        }
        else {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }

    if (-not $Data) {
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " No data found")
    }

    #schtasks /delete /F /TN $TaskName
    $Task_Folder.DeleteTask($TaskName, 0)
    Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is deleted")

    #$File, $Script, $Launcher | Remove-Item -EA Ignore
    Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp files removed")
} -ComputerName $Computer -ArgumentList $User, 'Test'
```

Comment: I suggest providing a short example that contains only the absolute minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, it seemed that the Scheduled Task only kicked of the script but didn't stay in status `Running` until it was done. This was fixed by modifying the VB Code to the following:

```
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File .\PS_Script.ps1", 0, True
```

Hope this helps someone.

Below the full and enhanced version with al the right pauses for the scheduled tasks to be created and checked properly:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$TaskName
    )

    $VerbosePreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$Using:VerbosePreference
    $DebugPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$Using:DebugPreference

    $CurrentDir = 'C:\Users\' + $User + '\AppData\Local\Temp'
    $Script     = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Script.ps1'
    $Launcher   = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Launcher.vbs'
    $File       = $CurrentDir + '\PS_Data.txt'

    $File, $Script, $Launcher | Remove-Item -EA Ignore

    #region Create temp files
    Try {
        # VB is only needed to kick-of the script and suppress the PowerShell window and to set the workdir
        $VBCode = @"
            'run window totally hidden
            Dim oSHELL
            Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            oSHELL.CurrentDirectory = "$CurrentDir"
            oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File .\PS_Script.ps1", 0, True
            Set oSHELL = Nothing
"@
        $VBCode | Set-Content $Launcher -EA Stop
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created '$Launcher'")

        $PSCode = {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

            Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | Select-Object Name, ProviderName |
                Export-Csv .\PS_Data.txt -NoTypeInformation
        }
        $PSCode | Set-Content $Script -EA Stop
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created '$Script'")
    }
    Catch {
        throw "User profile folder '$CurrentDir' not found on '$env:COMPUTERNAME'"
    }
    #endregion

    Try {
        #region Create scheduled task
        #schtasks /create /F /RL HIGHEST /SC ONCE /ST 23:00 /TN $TaskName /TR "wscript.exe $Launcher" /RU "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$User"
        $Task = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
        $Task.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)
        $Task_Folder = $Task.GetFolder('\')
        $Task_TaskDefinition = $Task.NewTask(0)

        $Task_RegistrationInfo = $Task_TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
        $Task_RegistrationInfo.Description = 'This task is created with PowerShell to run with user credentials'
        $Task_RegistrationInfo.Author = 'Powershell'

        $Task_Settings = $Task_TaskDefinition.Settings
        $Task_Settings.Enabled = $True
        $Task_Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $True
        $Task_Settings.Hidden = $False
        $Task_Settings.AllowDemandStart = $True
        $Task_Settings.WakeToRun = $True
        $Task_Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = $False
        $Task_Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = $False

        $Task_Action = $Task_TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
        $Task_Action.Path = 'wscript.exe'
        $Task_Action.Arguments = $Launcher
        $Task_Action.WorkingDirectory = $CurrentDir

        $Task_Folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName, $Task_TaskDefinition, 6, ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN + '\' + $User), $null, 3) | Out-Null
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is created")
        #endregion

        #region Run scheduled task
        $StartDateUTC = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
        schtasks /run /TN $TaskName | Write-Verbose
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is started as user '$User'")
        #endregion

        #region Wait for scheduled task to finish
        # Initial wait time because tasks don't start fast enough
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

        while ($Task_Folder.GetTask($TaskName).State -ne 3) {
            Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled Task '$TaskName' is running")
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is finished")
        #endregion


        #region Check eventlog for failures because user might not be logged in
        $Date ="{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}.{6}z" -f $StartDateUTC.Year, $StartDateUTC.Month, $StartDateUTC.Day, 
            $StartDateUTC.Hour, $StartDateUTC.Minute, $StartDateUTC.Second, $StartDateUTC.Millisecond

        # Initial wait time for the task to write to the eventlog
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

        $Problems = Get-WinEvent -ErrorAction Ignore -FilterXml @"
            <QueryList>
              <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
                <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
                    *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\$TaskName'] and 
                    *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler'] and 
                    (Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3) and 
                    TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='$Date']]]</Select>
              </Query>
            </QueryList>
"@
        if ($Problems) {
            if ($Problems.Message -like '*2147943645*') {
                throw "The scheduled task can only run when the user is logged on to the client, because we use the user's credentials to run this task."
            }
            else {
                throw $Problems.Message
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    Catch {
        throw "Failed creating/running the scheduled rask '$TaskName' on '$env:COMPUTERNAME': $_"
    }

    #region Get results
    if (Test-Path $File) {
        Import-Csv $File | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID
        Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp file created and data imported '$File'")            
    }
    else {
            Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " No data found")
    }
    #endregion

    #region Delete temp files and task
    #schtasks /delete /F /TN $TaskName
    $Task_Folder.DeleteTask($TaskName, 0)
    Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Scheduled task '$TaskName' is deleted")

    $File, $Script, $Launcher | Remove-Item -EA Ignore
    Write-Verbose ($env:COMPUTERNAME + " Temp files removed")
    #endregion
} -ComputerName $Computer -ArgumentList $User, 'Test'
```